# Analyse data dependency between functions with callgraph using vagrind

Tags: multithreading, valgrind, multicore, callgrind

I am trying to do multithread programming for a multicore ARM processor. I use valgrind for profiling. I can see from the callgraph of function calls under main function. How to interpret the data dependency between functions? Two of my functions are branching out from the main function and I assumed it means there is no data dependency between them and can run in parallel but it is not. Can someone explain with an example or where to know about it?

Answer (score 0):

Callgrind (and its visualisation tool kcachegrind) do *not* show what part of your program can be run in parallel.
Callgrind is a profiler : it shows which part of your program is consuming
CPU, or is doing a lot of cache misses, or ...
kcachegrind visualises the call graph to show this consumption.
If you see an arrow between main and other functions, it just means that
main has called these functions.

I do not know a tool that analyses a program and determines what could run
in parallel.

Valgrind however has 2 tools that can detect race conditions in a multi-thread
program. Once you have parallelised your algorithm, these tools could detect bugs (such as unprotected access to shared variables).